# How to add tooltip to Gmap.Net polygon?

Tags: tooltip, polygon, gmap.net

I'm using Gmap.net great tools for enable mapping in my .net 4 desktop application.
I'm adding polygons on form load event. But I can not set tooltip text for polygons.

any idea?

Comment: Please show your code and what you have tried so far.

Comment: But there is no TooltipText or Tooltip property or method for polygons in GMap.net. At least I could not find.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only way to do it that I found is add a marker on the same overlay, and trigger its `IsVisible` property when the polygon is entered:

```
var gm = new GMapControl();

GMapOverlay polyOverlay = new GMapOverlay("polygons");

List<PointLatLng> points = new List<PointLatLng>();
points.Add(new PointLatLng(53.0, 10.0));
points.Add(new PointLatLng(53.0, 11.0));
points.Add(new PointLatLng(54.0, 11.0));
points.Add(new PointLatLng(54.0, 10.0));

var polygon = new GMapPolygon(points, "mypolygon");

polygon.Fill = new SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(50, Color.Red));
polygon.Stroke = new Pen(Color.Red, 1);
polygon.IsHitTestVisible = true;

Controls.Add(gm);
gm.Overlays.Add(polyOverlay);
polyOverlay.Polygons.Add(polygon);

polyOverlay.Markers.Add(new GMarkerCross(new PointLatLng(53.5, 10.5)) { ToolTipText = "Test me", IsVisible = false, ToolTipMode = MarkerTooltipMode.Always });

gm.OnPolygonEnter += (poly) => polyOverlay.Markers.First().IsVisible = true;
gm.OnPolygonLeave += (poly) => polyOverlay.Markers.First().IsVisible = false;
```

Instead of `GMarkerCross` you could use a `GMarkerGoogle` with an empty `Bitmap`. Note: `GMarkerGoogleType.none` results in a `System.ArgumentNullException` when the mouse enters the polygon.

Comment: OK. thank you.  I'll test your method asap and I hope it solve my problem.

Comment: brilliant solution. Thanks a lot. this solved my problem.

Comment: how to determine which one is the selected polygon?

Comment: Can you elaborate what you mean? The sample above is having only one polygon for demo purposes. What are you trying to achieve? Might want to put up another question and provide more details?

Answer (score 1):

There is another way to add a ToolTip to a Polygon: Add a label to the form, and hide it in the Load event. Define your Polygon with a name in the usual way, and make sure to set IsHitTestVisible. Add handlers for the OnPolygonEnter and OnPolygonLeave.

```
Dim points As New List(Of PointLatLng)()
points.Add(New PointLatLng(48.866383, 2.323575))
points.Add(New PointLatLng(48.863868, 2.321554))
points.Add(New PointLatLng(48.861017, 2.33003))
points.Add(New PointLatLng(48.863727, 2.331918))
Dim polygon As New GMapPolygon(points, "Jardin des Tuileries")
polygon.Fill = New SolidBrush(Color.FromArgb(30, Color.Red))
polygon.Stroke = New Pen(Color.Red, 1)
polygon.IsHitTestVisible = True
ovlPolygons.Polygons.Add(polygon)

Private Sub myMap_OnPolygonEnter(item As GMapPolygon) Handles myMap.OnPolygonEnter
    Label1.BringToFront()
    Label1.Show()
    Label1.Text = item.Name
    Label1.Location = New Point(MousePosition.X - Me.Left, MousePosition.Y - Me.Top)
End Sub

Private Sub myMap_OnPolygonLeave(item As GMapPolygon) Handles myMap.OnPolygonLeave
    Label1.Hide()
End Sub
```